# SQL select query execution for change tracking on table takes longer time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Query which takes 14 seconds to execute for a single record.

```
SELECT CT.SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT 
FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES OrderDetail_MO_IN, 0) AS CT 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[OrderDetail_MO_IN] AS a ON CT.[MOB_RECORDID] = a.[MOB_RECORDID] 
    AND CT.[MOB_RECORDID] = a.[MOB_RECORDID] 
WHERE CT.SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT =CAST(N'11B1CE95-CD2B-4165-BCD6-090B83633573' AS    varbinary(128))
```

When I look at the **Execution Plan**, it shows 92% cost on the Sort operation and a warning "Operator used `tempdb` to spill data during execution with spill level 1".

Can anybody please let me know why the query is taking long time and how to optimize the query?

Regards,
Adarsh

Comment: Why use `CT.[MOB_RECORDID] = a.[MOB_RECORDID]` two times ?

Comment: My apologies, that JOIN is not required. I removed the JOIN altogether, but it does not make any difference. :(

Comment: Can you post the code for CHANGETABLE(CHANGES OrderDetail_MO_IN, 0) as well?

Comment: CHANGETABLE is a SQL Server function. It returns the change tracking information for a table.

Comment: Have you found what is the problem with this query? I have a similar query with same sort cost...